# Error when trying to make a comparator for a given class on a given field

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am trying to make a function that re returns a comparator on a field of a class, but I am getting an error when I am trying to get the value of o2, at the line `Comparable v2 = (Comparable) field.get(o2);`, saying that a lambda parameter cannot be converted to an object. Can someone help?

```
public Comparator comp(String className, String fieldName) throws Exception {
    Comparator comparator = Comparator.comparing((o1, o2) -> {
        Class aClass = null;
        try {
            aClass = Class.forName(className);
            Field field = aClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Comparable v1 = (Comparable) field.get(o1);
            Comparable v2 = (Comparable) field.get(o2);
            return v1.compareTo(v2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    });
    return comparator;
}
```

Comment: as a side note, don't use raw types.

Comment: Did you look at [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)? It doesn't expect a 2-arg function.

Comment: Where is this `fieldName` coming from? If it isn't user input, then it'd be much simpler to just use the method handle that `comparing` expects in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a Comparator.comparing method, but what you're passing in is actually an implementation of a comparator. You could just get rid of that method call and use:

```
Comparator comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
    Class aClass = null;
    try {
        aClass = Class.forName(className);
        Field field = aClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Comparable v1 = (Comparable) field.get(o1);
        Comparable v2 = (Comparable) field.get(o2);
        return v1.compareTo(v2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
};
return comparator;
```

---

Alternatively you could keep using the Comparator.comparing method, but keep in mind that you're supposed to pass in **a function that extracts the value of a field**:

```
public Comparator comp(String className, String fieldName) throws Exception {
    Class aClass = Class.forName(className);
    Field field = aClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Comparator comparator = Comparator.comparing(o1 -> {
        try {
            Comparable v1 = (Comparable) field.get(o1);
            return v1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    });
    return comparator;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be recommending the use of raw types.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer by Joni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60806935/5221149) correctly pointed out the error in your code.

In addition, you don't want to do the reflection lookup of the method on every `compare()` call, so do that lookup before creating the `Comparator`.

Also, your `comp()` method should be `static`.

```
public static Comparator comp(String className, String fieldName) throws Exception {
    Field field = Class.forName(className).getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return (o1, o2) -> {
        try {
            Comparable v1 = (Comparable) field.get(o1);
            Comparable v2 = (Comparable) field.get(o2);
            return v1.compareTo(v2);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // Should not happen because of setAccessible(true)
            throw new AssertionError("Unexpected error: " + e, e);
        }
    };
}
```

If you want to use `Comparator.comparing(...)`, then do it like this:

```
public static Comparator comp(String className, String fieldName) throws Exception {
    Field field = Class.forName(className).getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return Comparator.comparing(o -> {
        try {
            return (Comparable) field.get(o);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // Should not happen because of setAccessible(true)
            throw new AssertionError("Unexpected error: " + e, e);
        }
    });
}
```